# Posting a value that contains too many charcters and & char

Tags: javascript, http-post

I am trying to post some data to a php file by using following code.

```
var exam = document.getElementById("information").getAttribute("examid");
            var user = document.getElementById("information").getAttribute("userid");
            var question = document.getElementById("information").getAttribute("questionid");

            var xmlhttp;
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","savevalue.php?examid="+exam+"&userid="+user+"&questionid="+question+"&content="+ editor.getValue(),true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {

              }
            }
```

But the first problem is if the variable that I am posting contains too many characters, this method fails. Secondly if one of the variables that I am posting contains '&' char, it also fail. Should I replace `&` with something else?

Comment: If the data in one of the paramaters? What does that mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice: escape, or encodeURI / encodeURIComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Comment: I don't understand 1st problem...

Comment: If variables in the example like question and user have too many characters like 6000 characters , it fails.I mean that if var user="123" (3 chracters) , there is no problem but if it has more like 6000, it fails

Comment: beacuse you are supposed to use post as get has limitation.

Comment: to make ur life better i rather suggest you use jquery ajax unless you are not supposed to use jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, use the POST method instead of GET, because POST allows much more data/characters across in one message.

Also for the ampersand (&), that is a special character that needs to be escaped, or you could use `&amp;` notation